# One font by default a bit smaller using fontspec

Tags: xetex, fontspec, line-spacing, polyglossia

I have to typeset a few Hebrew words in a document, and for this I use `xelatex` with `polyglossia` and `fontspec` (MWE at the bottom). The problem is that this font has a larger x-height than the font I use for the rest of the document (the default). So it looks like this:

[image]

The distance between the 1st and 2nd, 2nd and 3rd, and 3rd and 4th line should all be the same.

How can I fix this? Is there a way to pass a default font size to `\DeclareTextFontCommand`? Then I could set the font size a bit lower so that this problem disappears.

A full MWE (requires the [Ezra SIL](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=ezrasil_home) font):

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{dutch}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily{\ezra}{Ezra SIL}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textezra}{\ezra}

\begin{document}

Nadruk op het in acht nemen van de geboden. Gebruikt net als E \textezra{אֱלֹהִים} tot Ex.~3, maar ook andere combinaties met \textezra{אֵל}. God is nog afstandelijker dan elders en manifesteert zichzelf in glorie. Nog wat meer tekst voor een laatste regel.

\end{document}
```

Comment: You could just scale down the ezra font: `\newfontfamily{\ezra}{Ezra SIL}[Scale=0.8]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alternatively, you can ask fontspec to scale the fonts according to your main font instead of using a trial-and-error number.

This is done by using either `MatchLowercase` or `MatchUppercase` as an argument to the `Scale` option.

In your case, you can declare your font as:

```
\newfontfamily{\ezra}{Ezra SIL}[Scale=MatchLowercase]
```

If you are using other fonts in your document (sans-serif, monospaced...) as well, you can declare the Scale option to be default for all loaded fonts by adding the following line after loading `fontspec` in your preamble:

```
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale = {MatchLowercase}}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can scale the font when you create your new font family with an additional font feature:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{dutch}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily{\ezra}{Ezra SIL}[Scale=0.8]
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textezra}{\ezra}

\begin{document}

Nadruk op het in acht nemen van de geboden. Gebruikt net als E \textezra{אֱלֹהִים} tot Ex.~3, maar ook andere combinaties met \textezra{אֵל}. God is nog afstandelijker dan elders en manifesteert zichzelf in glorie. Nog wat meer tekst voor een laatste regel.

\end{document}
```